# Converting raw sql query to Django ORM

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-orm

I have 3 models in my projec like this:

```
class Model_A(Models.Model):
  field_a_1 = models.IntegerField()
  ...other fields...

class Model_C(models.Model):
   field_c_1 = models.IntegerField()
   field_c_2 = models.IntegerField()
   ...other fields...

class Model_B(Model_C):
   table_a_fk_id = ChainedForeignKey(Model_A, .... ) 
   ...other fields...
```

Because of that in my database I have the following three tables:

```
Table_A(id, name, field_a_1, ...other fields....)                    
Table_B(id, table_a_fk_id, table_c_fk_id, .....other fields...)     
Table_C(id, field_c_1, field_c_2, ...other fields....)
```

and I need a query that retrive data like this output:

```
Table_A_id  Table_A_name                count
------------------------------------------------
12          Table_A_name_12               138
1           Table_A_name_1                133
13          Table_A_name_13                55
15          Table_A_name_15                38
9           Table_A_name_9                 34
7           Table_A_name_7                  0
19          Table_A_name_19                 0
```

I have solved the problem with a raw sql query, but I don't know how do the same in Django ORM.
This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT `Table_A`.`id` AS 'Table_A_id', `Table_A`.`nome` AS 'Table_A_name',
COUNT(`ptr`.`table_a_fk_id`) AS `count`
FROM `Table_A`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT `Table_C`.`id`, `Table_B`.`table_a_fk_id`
    FROM `Table_B`
    INNER JOIN `Table_C`
    ON ( `Table_B`.`table_c_fk_id` =`Table_C`.`id`)
    WHERE (
        `Table_B`.`table_a_fk_id` = xx
        AND `Table_C`.`field_c_1` = yy
        AND `Table_C`.`field_c_2` = zz
        ...other constraints on Table_C fields....
        )
    ) ptr
ON (`Table_A`.`id` = `ptr`.`table_a_fk_id`)
WHERE (`Table_A`.`field_a_1` = x )
GROUP BY `Table_A`.`id`
ORDER BY `count` DESC, `name` ASC
```

I want translate the above sql in Django ORM to avoid performing raw sql query.

Answer (score 0):

It could be argued, actually, that in this case you *would* be justified asking Django to do "a raw query," which of course you can do.

The argument I would make is – clarity.  What you're doing is obviously complex, *but* it is succinctly described by SQL syntax which is well-known to all programmers.  (And, should the need arise ... and, as we all know, it inevitably does ... it could be *changed* easily.)

I think that I could therefore make the case that you would be justified to use straight SQL here.  If I were your team-lead, that's probably what I would suggest.